# Fusionpbx login fails after IP address change

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have a similar problem. My first network had a IP address range 192.168.1.xx and my freepbx server had 192.168.1.2

However now I need to move to a new network which has IP address in the range 192.168.2.xx and my freepbx server had 192.168.2.2

Now if I try to login to my freepbx server connected to the new network, the login always fails. Can anyhow help how to ensure freepbx/freeswitch will work on the new ip address?

thanks, -Anish

Comment: Try login by using username: admin@192.168.1.2

Comment: the network IP address has changed from 1.xx to 2.xx. So point in trying admin@192.168.1.2    192.168.1.2 is a invalid IP address in the new environment

Comment: I have done changing network segment as well sometime ago. That time, it worked, I can login to FusionPBX by using username@old_fusionpx_IP.

Answer (score 1):

The users are per domain in FusionPBX.  If you don't login with "user@192.168.1.2" then it will default to domain 192.168.2.2 that you use to access the website.

Once you have logged in you can edit the domain to change it's name.  Also check for the old IP address in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your account. Go to `/etc/fusionpbx` repository, you must found a file `config.conf` or `config.php`. Move it like this :

```
mv config.conf config.conf.tmp
```

Or

```
mv config.php config.php.tmp
```

And open the fusionPBX dashboard link, it should ask you for a new password and domain.

PS : In database step, fill data using db configuration already exist in file `config.conf.tmp` or `config.php.tmp`